# find task priority levels of rtos

Tags: rtos

I am working on a research about the performance evaluation about various RTOS for embedded system. But I found the information is not easy to get. I've read a paper which discusses the number of priority levels of different RTOS. Then I tried to find how many levels for AVIX operating system. But I can't find it. Are there any tips to search this kind of information?

Comment: Tip: email or call the rtos developer and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is performance data not always easy to obtain, but for commercial RTOS in many cases publication of performance data derived from comparative testing is explicitly prohibited in the licence agreement.  So you will be restricted in what you can do with this information.

You can probably determine what you need from the API documentation.  You have to register with AVIX to get access to their downloads section, but I would imagine the information is available there.

That said the number of priority levels has no bearing on performance.